# How to ban python's tags completion when to edit php file?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, tags

Here is some  completion config in my .vimrc for  python , php.

```
au FileType python call pyFun()
function pyFun()
    set  tags+=/home/debian8/.vim/python.tags
    autocmd FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete  
endfunction

au FileType php call phpFun()
function phpFun()    
    autocmd FileType php set  omnifunc=phpcomplete#Complete
endfunction
```

python.tags  was created by ctags.

```
ctags -R --fields=+l --languages=python --python-kinds=-iv  -o   /tmp/python3.tag   anaconda3/lib/python3.6
```

Now to edit a file `test.php`.
To call tags completion with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> after chracters `fil`,words menu  pop up.
[image]

There is no  function such as  fileConfig and fileDescriptorReceived in php.

```
grep 'fileConfig'  /home/debian8/.vim/tag/python.tag
fileConfig  anaconda3/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py   /^def fileConfig(fname, defaults=None, disable_existing_loggers=True):$/;"  f
grep 'fileDescriptorReceived'  /home/debian8/.vim/tag/python.tag
fileDescriptorReceived  anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/endpoints.py /^    def fileDescriptorReceived(self, descriptor):$/;" m   class:_WrappingProtocol
```

All of them is not i wanted.
How to ban vim to call python's tag when to edit php file,in other words ,
all of them can't be displayed when to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> after chracters `fil`?

Answer (score 1):

Create or edit files `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` and `~/.vim/ftplugin/php.vim`.

In `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` add:

```
setlocal tags+=/home/debian8/.vim/python.tags
setlocal omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
```

In `~/.vim/ftplugin/php.vim`:

```
setlocal omnifunc=phpcomplete#Complete
```

Comment: To set nnothing more in the .vimrc?

Comment: It is no use to set python.vim and php.vim only.

Comment: Set `filetype plugin indent on` (or at least `filetype on`) in `.vimrc`.

Comment: I tested it is no use to add filetype plugin indent on in .vimrc.